# Joins using foreign key codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, join

What is wrong with my code please? 
I selected a identifier of a student and I stored it in the session, then I tested on this to select the corresponding value from a table,  and from the result I want to get the table I'm looking for, but it doesnt work. 
Heres the situation, well I have three tables absence_student(CNE,Idabsence), , Absence(iabsence , ....) and I want to get the rows from absence that correspond to id_student(CNE).

```
public function absence(){
$id2= $this->session->CNE;
$this->db->select('id_absence');
            $this->db->from('absence_etudiant');
            $this->db->where('CNE',$id2);
            $query = $this->db->get();
             $row=$query->row();
 if($query->num_rows() == 1)
{ 

    $id_abs = $row->id_absence;

}

$this->db->select('*');
             $this->db->from('absence');
            $this->db->where('id_absence',$id_abs);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            $result=$query->result();
$this->load->view('Etudiants/affi',$result);


 }
```

Comment: What part of this doesn't work? Are you getting a value for `$id_abs`? If you are, does a record really exist in "absense" meeting the condition `where('id_absence',$id_abs)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest query to get the data you want it using a join. Instead of using Query Builder I will use `db->query()`

```
public function absence(){
    $id2= $this->session->CNE;
    $query = $this->db->query("Select * From absence_etudiant Inner Join absence On absence.id_absence = absence_etudiant.CNE Where absence_etudiant.CNE = $id2");

    $data['absences'] = $query->result();
    $this->load->view('Etudiants/affi', $data);
}
```

I may not have joined the correct fields. I'm not sure I understand the table structures involved. This is my best attempt working from the code in your question.

The query results will be available in the view in the var `$absences`. In the view file a table that prints one row for each of the absences can be created as follows.

```
  <table> 
    <?php foreach($absences as $absence) : ?>
      <tr> 
        <td><strong><?php echo $absence->id_absence; ?></strong></td>
        <td><?php echo $absence->id_seance; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $absence->justification; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $absence->course; ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </table>
```

I don't show how to create the table's header row but if you wanted one it would be put between the `<table>` tag and the `foreach` loop.

I should add that the other answer from elddenmedio does a better job of showing how to structure this process using MVC principals. He has the controller get results from a model and then pass the model's return to the view.

Comment: if im not bothering how would i display the result please <table>
     <tr>
      <td><strong>id_absence</strong></td>
    
    </tr>
     <?php foreach($data->result() as $r){?>
     <tr>
         <td><?php echo $r->id_absence;?></td>
          ??

Comment: please how to display it is it  foreach $data->result as $result ? I dont get it

Comment: I have updated my answer to show what could be done in a view.

Answer (score 0):

can yo send more ifno about your tables relation.

I can only help you with this query

controller.php

```
function absence(){
    $data['result']   = $this->model->get_absence($this->session->CNE);

    $this->load->view('Etudiants/affi', $data);
}
```

model.php

```
function get_absence($id){
    $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM absence a WHERE a.id_absence IN (SELECT ae.id_absence FROM absence_etudiant ae WHERE ae.CNE = '.$id.' ORDER BY ae.CNE LIMIT 1)');
    $result = $this->db->get()->result();

    return $result;
}
```

Hope, this help you

Comment: now im getting this error  database error no table used

Comment: can you send a screen shot about the error and the info about your 2 tables

Comment: there are the tables                                       absence_student(id_absence,CNE)                                                                                 absence (id_absence , id_seance, justification, course  ),  student (CNE , name )   I want the student to be able   to check his absence by courses  andto justify it

Comment: Hi, i a moment I´ll send you a new query with the 3 tables, by the way, in my answer I wrote the name in se second query wrong, can you check it

Comment: The query will be like `SELECT s.name, s.CNE FROM bsence_student as INNER JOIN absence a ON as.id_absence = a.id_absence INNER JOIN student s ON as.CNE = s.CNE WHERE s.CNE = $id ORDER BY s.CNE  LIMIT 1`

Comment: Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN absence a ON ae.id_absence = a.id_absence INNER JOIN etudiants s ON a' at line 1

SELECT ae.id_absence, ae.CNE FROM absence_student as INNER JOIN absence a ON ae.id_absence = a.id_absence INNER JOIN etudiants s ON ae.CNE = s.CNE WHERE s.CNE = $id ORDER BY s.CNE LIMIT 1

Filename: C:/wamp/www/tpp/system/database/DB_driver.php

Comment: would you please the answer above of DFriend  seems like its working but i dont know how todisplay the result

Comment: With the DFriend answer you need to change this `$data['absences'] = $query->result();` to `$data['absences'] = $this->db->get()->result()`; and in your view make a var_dump to print the result and choose the correct way to display it (foreach, echo, print_f, etc)

Comment: how would I do it using foreach ? I dont get it , im a newbie in this

Comment: yes, if you make a var_dump in your view and you see that you have many rows, you can use foreach like `foreach($absences as $item => $value){ echo $tiem . ' - ' . $value . '<br>';}`

Comment: @elddenmedio, There is no need to use `get()` when using `$this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");` The function `get()` is part of "Query Builder" which I am not using in my answer.

Comment: It's null it has no data actually